# Laravel hasMany not returning collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building the middleware for permissions.
Permissions are based on either user action types and/or module/element type (i.e. delete button).

The model `ActionPermission` (table `action_permission`) has all the permission types while table `users__action_permission` is the pivot for `User` & `ActionPermission` with all users and their permission IDs.

#### `User`

has a `permissions()` method that gets all the permissions for user

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ActionPermission');
}
```

#### `checkUserPermissions` (middleware)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        $response = $next($request);
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $userPermissions = User::findOrFail($userId)->permissions()->get();
        dd($userPermissions);
}
```

Since `permissions()` is looking for `user_id` key, and `ActionPermission` model (table `action_permission`) does not have the relevant `user_id` key, I need the table `users__action_permission` which holds he `user_id`.

My question is if Laravel has a way for `User::permissions()` to access `users__action_permission` table, or do I need to build a model for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a model for the pivot table.

in User model
add

```
public function ActionPermissions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_action_permission');
}
```

in Action Permission model
add

```
public function Users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ActionPermission', 'users_action_permission');
}
```